# Rails 4 / ActiveRecord Querying Times Improved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After upgrading to Rails 3, I discovered this article on Rails 3 performance that discusses benchmarks that show Rails 3 to be considerably slower by 2x and is Rails 3's ActiveRecord to be the culprit:

http://pulse.sportngin.com/news_article/show/86942

Does anyone know if Rails 4 will have worked out this issue? or even found a Rails 3 solution?

Answer (score 0):

That article doesn't state any specifics about the application, on which it ran. So there could be local differences that makes 3 run faster. And you should also choose the right server for your application use, not just any old server. So I suggest running your own benchmarks, with the specific needs of your application.